# how to store return values from void in C?

Tags: c, return-value, void, function-call

How to store values from void function in main ?

Example

```
void UsartCallback (uchar* buf, uint len)
{
    return void(*buf);
}

int main()
{
    UsartCallback(&buf,1); // I can get values from void function but how to store this "*buf" value
    // For Example 
    uchar* data=UsartCallback(&buf); //Error: but i want get only "buf" value from void function.
}
```

Comment: *void*, by definition, does *not* return value. You should just call it without assignment: `UsartCallback(&buf)`. The `uchar* data` part is unnecessary

Comment: no i can return value that i have shown above.

Comment: What thought process led to the decision to tag a C question [tag:c++] and [tag:c#], pray tell?

Comment: Unclear, and you've changed the language twice, now changed the question a few times in comments too. -1

Comment: Observing response comments in existing answers, Voting to close as unclear....

Answer (score 2):

You probably want this:

```
void *UsartCallback (uchar* buf, uint len)
{
  return (void*)buf;
}

int main()
{
  uchar *mybuf = UsartCallback(&buf,1);
}
```

Comment: Oh, right. hah.

Comment: ah, that is a void *pointer*

Comment: Maybe, maybe not, we passed pointer to `buf` as argument...... :)

Comment: @user3764118 so your code is different from the code in this answer. Where _exactly_ did you get this error? Maybe you should ask a new question about this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is **invalid** code, as it violates the constraint.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.8.6.4

> A `return` statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type
>   is `void`. [...]

Comment: can i do this in C++ ?

Comment: @user3764118 why?

Comment: @user3764118 Dude are you writing C or is it C++? Would you please _pick one_?

Comment: Or is ti C# maybe?

Comment: ok, i'm bit confused because i wrote file in C so that way i mention as "C" so is it possible in C++

Comment: @tilz0R why not ruby? python? go? fortan? asm, maybe? :P

Comment: Before you hate, original post had tags for c c++ and c#. @SouravGhosh

Comment: @tilz0R OK, i think you got me wrong... 1) i'm the one who edited them out. 2) my question was not "targeted" to you and it's rhetorical...hope it's clear now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There is no such thing as a "void value". `void` is the absence of a value. It is true that it *looks like* you're returning a "thing" here, but you're not.

- In C, this is illegal and your program doesn't even compile.
- In C++, the code is accepted as an "oddity" of syntax (this is for making templates easier to implement). Your line is effectively the same as `return;`.

---

> ok is there any way to get "buf" value from void and i want to store that in "main" .. is it possible ?

Okay, completely different question now.

`buf` is a pointer. So, yes, simply return it. Presumably your callback is required to return `void*` by some external force?

```
void* UsartCallback (uchar* buf, uint len)
{
    return buf;
}
```

I suggest you brush up on pointer syntax; your question (if I now understand it correctly; really hard to tell) betrays a lack of understanding of how to work with pointer types.

Comment: ok is there any way to get "buf" value from void and i want to store that in "main" .. is it possible ?